# Java DataOutputStream object flushes after 8192 bytes

Tags: java

I'm having a Java variable declared as such:

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("path-to-file");
DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file.getFD())));
```

The problem is that after 2048 introduced integers (or 8192 bytes), if I try to write another one, the output flushes to disk without any warning.

After some research I found out that DataOutputStream has a 64k limit, and I couldn't find anything official about BufferedOutputStream or FileOutputStream.

Can anybody please tell me which structure has this limitation and how can I increase it?

It would also be nice to find out why does the structure flush without being told to instead of just raising an exception?

Comment: So why are you using a buffered output steam on a random access file?

Comment: What made you think it would raise an exception? The point of buffering is to improve efficiency - if you're trying to use it so that you can explicitly stop the data from being written until you flush it, I'd suggest writing your own stream wrapper for that.

Comment: Do mean apart from the javadoc for BufferedOutputStream which is clearly the class responsible for buffering?

Comment: I couldn't find the number of bytes mentioned in the docs. Also I couldn't have known for which reason the stream flushes after adding 8k to it. That's why I asked the question here. Anyway, I got the desired answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the `BufferedOutputStream` who flushes, whose default size is **8192**:

```
public BufferedOutputStream(OutputStream out) {
     this(out, 8192);
}
```

Just create the `BufferedOutputStream` with a seconds parameter describing the wanted buffer size!

```
int BUFFER_SIZE= <some value>;

DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file.getFD()), BUFFER_SIZE));
```

However, this might not be what you want!
Queuing writes and writing them in one big chunk (at flush) is the very purpose of the `BufferedOutputStream` and it increases performance considerably. It's not at all a problem when it flushes. Just make sure that it flushes after you made your last write.

Additionally, I'm pretty sure you got the 64K limit of the `DataOutputStream` wrong!
Itself will write unlimited bytes, however it will only write strings with a maximum length of 64K when encoded as UTF-8.
It also contains a counter how many bytes have been written. Obviously this one will overflow after `Integer.MAX_VALUE` written bytes, but that shouldn't matter!

Comment: Thanks. Still I didn't find on the documentation page of BufferedOutputStream its default buffer value or the fact that it flushes when the buffer is full.

Comment: @user2565010: I can't find that one in the docs indeed... But with the JDK download you also got the sources. Just link them in your IDE and youre just one <CTRL>+<LMB> click away from the full source! (in IntelliJ)

Comment: @user2565010 The Javadic clearly states 'flushing the nuffer to the underlying output stream *as necessary*'. There is really no excuse for this misunderstanding on your part.

Comment: @EJP: Yeah, but the default buffer size is missing, which surprised me. Another reason to fully specify all parameter in constructors...

Comment: I image the exact default size is not given is because a) if it matters you will specify it b) the optimal buffer size could be different on different systems and if specified in the docs it could not be easily tuned.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: But the buffer size is hardcoded... Do they ship different classes per OS?

Comment: @StackOverflowException They often ship different classes per vendor. e.g. IBM or Azul could use a different value if they wanted to.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Hm, okay, one thing less to rely on...

Comment: @StackOverflowException If it is in the Javadoc, then the vendors should comply with what it says.  If not, a vendor can choose to change it even if the OpenJDK source suggests otherwise.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Of course, but that also means, that even *if* I have the source code for a class I can't be 100% sure it has the same behaviour elsewhere. Obviously they shouldn't change behaviour, but can I be sure?

Comment: @StackOverflowException the source between versions can change dramatically.  Take HashMap for example, In Java 6, 7 and 8 the hashing algo looks completely different.  In Java 7 update 4, they changed String.substring() from reusing an old char[] to always taking a copy.  That is just in a minor update.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Nah, I didn't knew that one as well... I'll continue to use the String copy constructor nonetheless!

Comment: The `-XX:+UseCompressString` is documented as being on by default n http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html  Actually it is off in many updates (including the latest of Java 6) and not even recognised in Java 7 (It won't start if you use it) I could go on, .... :P

Comment: @EJP - You sure that isn't "fluffing the nuffer"? ;)

Comment: @EJP You're right, I didn't see that part in the javadoc. Still, I wouldn't agree about its inability to be misunderstood. "As necessary" is not exactly a clear term. Of course, in my case I would have immediately connected it to my problem, but unless that expression is also explained and properly made known, it can mean anything. If it were "flushing the buffer when it is at full capacity which by default is 8192 bytes" or something similar, then in that case there wouldn't be room for misunderstanding.